# How combine two different Paths

Tags: c#, path

I have two different Paths:

`C:\Project\v4.0\Tool\Custom\CustomCompanyNames\Template\file\file.xml
C:\Destination\New\Place\Bin\Debug\output`

I need a way two get values from two different paths

Expected Path:

`C:\Destination\New\Place\Bin\Debug\output\CustomCompanyNames\file\file.xml`

How can i solve it ?

- Custom is a fix folder
- All directories after Customs have different names

My Solution bad programmed:

- Custom ist the first path
- Destination the second path

  ```
    private void test()
    {
      string result = destination;

      string[] custom = customs.Split('\\');

      foreach (var s in custom)
      {

          if(s.Contains("custom") || result.Contains("custom"))
          {
              if(s.Contains("templates")) break;
              result = Path.Combine(result, s);
          }
      }
   }
  ```

Comment: Have you tried anything? After splitting the upper path you can use `Path.Combine`

Comment: I tried to split the path and combine the code. But my problem is to trim the directory \Template

Comment: Nobody says do it for me. I edited my solution @GiladGreen

Comment: now it is a good question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Split`ting the path use `IndexOf` to find the `Custom` part and then `Substring` from it.

```
string path1 = @"C:\Project\v4.0\Tool\Custom\CustomCompanyNames\Template\file\file.xml";
string path2 = @"C:\Destination\New\Place\Bin\Debug\output";

string splitter = @"Custom\";
string desiredSection = path1.Substring(path1.IndexOf(splitter) + splitter.Length);

string output = Path.Combine(path2, desiredSection);
```

Comment: Thanks. The Code looks so easy :) but the output is C:\\Destination\\New\\Place\\Bin\\Debug\\output\\CustomCompanyNames\\Template\\file\\file.xml How can i trim the Template\\ ?

Comment: @Mo_Code - This is a followup question... My answer still solved the original question of how to join the two paths.. If you want to remove the `Template` part then you can use `.Replace()`